# What is the proper way to add same component everytime a button is clicked?

Tags: vue.js

I am creating a form which needs to have a button and when clicked a new component which is only an input field would be added.

For example I have only one field to put in my address, but my adress is very long so I need 2 additional input fields. I click a button twice and two more components with the input appear.

What is a proper way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: You should check this example.https://codepen.io/izobiz/pen/vgeWaY

Comment: @Riddhi thank you, that is very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution to your question.
https://jsfiddle.net/RiddhiParekh/usd57zkb/6/

Template =>

```
 <div id="vue-instance">
    <button @click="addInput">Click to add input</button>
    <br>
    Address:
        <div v-for="i in count">
          <input type="text">
          </div>
    </div>
```

Script =>

```
  var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#vue-instance',
      data: {
       count:1
      },
      methods:{
      addInput(){
      this.count = this.count+1
      }
      }
    });
```